# add buttons dynamically based on screen size

Tags: android

I have about 10 buttons, and these 10 should be displayed based on the screen width. If the screen width is lesser, then a "more" button should be displayed and on click of more , the remaining buttons should be displayed as a pop up on more button. 
I have tried this 
[Add Buttons dynamically depending on screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030172/add-buttons-dynamically-depending-on-screen-width)
But width consideration is troubling me.. Could some one help me out in this regard

Comment: You need to post your code if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you

```
Display display =((WindowManager)activityContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayWidth = display.getWidth();
        DisplayHeight = display.getHeight();

        if(DisplayHeight > DisplayWidth)
        {
            ButtonWidth = (6 * DisplayWidth) / 7 ;
            ButtonHeight = (4 * DisplayHeight) / 5 ;
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonWidth = (6 * DisplayWidth) / 9 ;
            ButtonHeight = (4 * DisplayHeight) / 5 ;
        }
```

Divide and multiply display width and height as per your requirement and set as button width and height.

Comment: I dont want to vary the width and height of the button. They have to remain the same, the excess buttons should be stacked under a "more" button